# Read Lines from document and create new document accordingly

Tags: windows, batch-file

I would like to ask you to help me with one script in windows 7,

Input: list of files in txt file like this:

```
File1.dll 
File2.txt
File3.png ....
```

Output is:

```
<A>
  <FILE_NAME>File1.dll</FILE_NAME>
</A>
<A>
  <FILE_NAME>File2.txt</FILE_NAME>
</A>
<A>
  <FILE_NAME>File3.png</FILE_NAME>
</A>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%x in (files.txt) do (
    echo.^<A^>
    echo.    ^<FILE_NAME^>%%x^</FILE_NAME^>
    echo.^</A^>
)
```